# Magento 1.9 Custom Module Class not Found

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am new in magento. i try to create a custom Module, for admin from tutorial, and when i try to access admin panel i got `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mage_Sample_Helper_Data' not found`.

And if i disable the module , admin work fine.

Can't understand from where come the **Mage**  alias instead **Lern**

thank you for help.

files look like this:

**folders:**

```
app
  code
    local
      Lern
        Sample
```

**config.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <config>
       <modules>
         <Lern_Sample>
           <version>0.1.0</version>
         </Lern_Sample>
       </modules>
       <frontend>
         <routers>
           <sample>
             <use>standard</use>
               <args>
                 <module>Lern_Sample</module>
                 <frontName>sample</frontName>
              </args>
           </sample>
         </routers>
       </frontend>
      <admin>
       <routers>
         <sample>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Lern_Sample</module>
                <frontName>admin_sample</frontName>
            </args>
        </sample>
       </routers>
      </admin>
  <global>
    <helpers>
        <helloworld>
            <class>Lern_Sample_Helper</class>
        </helloworld>
    </helpers>
</global>
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <sample module="sample">
            <title>Sample Module</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <sample module="sample">
                    <title>Sample Module</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>admin_sample/adminhtml_index</action>
                </sample>
            </children>
        </sample>
    </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

**Helpers folder - file Data.php**

```
 class Lern_Sample_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

  }
```

**Adminhtml controller:**

```
class Lern_Sample_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

/**
 * Admin controller index action
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */

public function indexAction() {

    echo 'hello world in the admin side..!!!'. '';

   }
 }
```

Comment: does Magento work when you disable your module?

Comment: sec i will tryit

Comment: Yes it is working when i'm disable the module

Comment: then I have a feeling it's to do with your `helper` class. Also just so you know, support for Magento1.X is due to stop shortly .. so no more security updates etc. - should research Magento 2 :)

Comment: i need it for a work. i got exersize from new company about a job. and they work with 1.9 :)

Comment: i found error in xml, instead helloworld should be sample

Comment: you should mention it to them briefly - it's pretty darn important to keep safe, especially in an eCommerce business :) and ahh I see well at least you found the issue:)

Comment: thanks for a help anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Your helper is called because you declared `sample` as the helper's module that should be called for translating your menu's titles. But the problem is that in your `config.xml`, you declared your helpers for your module callable via the string `helloworld` and not `sample`.
Two ways to fix it.

First way (and the most consistent here, given the name of your module), modify your helper's call like this :

```
<helpers>
    <sample>
        <class>Lern_Sample_Helper</class>
    </sample>
</helpers>
```

OR second way, modify the module's helper called in your menu declaration, like this :

```
<menu>
    <sample module="helloworld">
        <title>Sample Module</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
            <sample module="helloworld">
                <title>Sample Module</title>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <action>admin_sample/adminhtml_index</action>
            </sample>
        </children>
    </sample>
</menu>
```